# StreamReader, Bad Request (400)

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

We have a website that allow firmware downloads.

Somwhere along the way it uses a StreamReader. For some unknown reason, some customer (In Israel) get a 400 Bad Request error. Everyone else do not get this error.

Any1 out there experienced the same thing ? Anyone got a clue ?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strURL = Request.Url.Host;
    System.Net.WebRequest reqPT = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://" + strURL + "/Products/ProductTree.asp");
    System.IO.StreamReader srPT = new System.IO.StreamReader(reqPT.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
    dvPT.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(srPT.ReadToEnd()));
}
```

It crashes, for them only, at the new StreamReader.

Thank you !

UPDATE : We noticed that the customer is actually loosing the "www" in the address (strURL), wich cause the error. Why would someone, (clicking on the same link as the rest of the planet is) would loose the www ?? I'm seeing 2 differents behavior for the exact same code :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well with the HTTP 400 error the requested URL is probably invalid, and since the literals in your `System.Net.WebRequest` look OK, my guess is your Israeli user is requesting the page using a different `Request.Url.Host` than everyone else.  Can you debug and verify the value of `strUrl`?

Comment: @pseudocoder I checked the URL, it's perfect. The customer sent a screenshot. But his FireFox is in Hebrew, could that be a factor ?

Comment: @David well the request isn't formulated by the client browser so that shouldn't matter.  If `strURL` is the value you want then it should be processed the same for any user.  When you say you checked the URL, do you mean you checked the address bar in his screenshot?  If so I think you should look deeper into what is happening on the server side during processing of his request.

Comment: @Pseudocoder tkx for the tip ! The strURL is actually missing the www, but not for everyone ! Even if it's the same link for everyone !?

Comment: @David Hmm strange.  I don't know if I can explain that one, but glad I led you to the source of the problem.  Is it possible that the user requested domain.com vs www.domain.com in the original request?  Don't forget to mark as answer if you feel that is appropriate.

Comment: @pseudocoder the original request was with www ... very strange. I'll accept your answer if by tomorrow no one came with a better solution/tip. Anyway thank you ;)